# Angular 5.0.3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name

Tags: angular, golden-layout

I am trying to leverage `golden-layout` docking library. I have everything installed for my angular project but I am hitting an error that I cannot seem to get around.

```
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-11-28T04:04:54.440Z                                                t Hash: bff1ad470576d56127a4
Time: 28376ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.93 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 636 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 503 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 854 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(15,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(64,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(138,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(668,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(766,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(771,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(776,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(818,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(823,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
node_modules/golden-layout/index.d.ts(828,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.


webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I saw other another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954533/golden-layout-anulgar-2-ng-golden-layout) and it is blank with no answers. When I originally got this error I did some research. I realized there was a typings problem. I went directly to the module files, and I could see the errors in the `index.d.ts` file. `JQuery` reference could not be found. So I googled around on how to fix that. The solution was to run `npm install @typings/jquery`. This solved my errors in the file. However, I am still getting the errors from cli when I try to run `ng serve` even though the errors are fixed in the `index.d.ts` file. I am sort of at a loss on how to move forward here.

Is there a way to just use the javascript file in angular instead of trying to use the module? Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FITTtt?p=preview) of it working with angular. I can see that they are just adding the script file directly to the index.html file. I have added the script file to the `angular-cli.json` file and it does not fix the problem. Angular still tries to use the module and hence the typing file. Any ideas or potential solutions? I feel like there is a cache somewhere that needs to be reset because I fixed the `@typings` error.

Comment: just needed to add the TS compiler option `--skipDefaultLibCheck` ....don't like it. Not sure of the implications entirely yet.

Comment: did u get your problem solved. I am going through the same

Comment: yeah, its in the comment above but again that was back in 2017.

Comment: I got it solved after install jquery types.