# Multi-window dockable layout manager for Angular2 WebApps

Tags: javascript, angular, golden-layout

Is there a multi-window layout manager for Angualar 2 based webapps ?

I found examples like this:

http://golden-layout.com/

http://www.dockspawn.com/

http://docker.api.webcabin.org/index.html

But the problem is that there is no Angular 2 integration for these plugins.

Comment: related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954533/golden-layout-anulgar-2-ng-golden-layout